# How to solve Warning: stream_wrapper_unregister() [function.stream-wrapper-unregister]

Tags: php

I am try to generate Excel file of my search with `PHPExcel` library its working fine on local but on the live server raises an error:

> Warning: `stream_wrapper_unregister()` [function.stream-wrapper-unregister]: `Unable to unregister protocol zip://` in /home/crazyfirew/domains/thundershow.nl/public_html/kruidenier/admin/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/ZipStreamWrapper.php on line 69
>
> Fatal error: Class `'ZipArchive'` not found in /home/crazyfirew/domains/thundershow.nl/public_html/kruidenier/admin/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php on line 234

I googled about this error and found that I have to add `extension=php_zip.dll;` in `php.ini` file but it's not working. Does anyone know how can I remove this error?

Comment: `php_zip.dll` is for windows/`php_zip.so` for unix and you need to have that `dll`/`so` in extension path, also you need to restart apache after you modify `php.ini`

Comment: am use both extension but still is not working .. am checked PHP configuration after adding these extension but don't unable the extensions ..

Comment: If you can't enable ZipArchive on your live server, then you can configure PHPExcel to use PCLZip instead for writing Excel2007 files

Comment: @Mark Baker: Thanks for your response ... there is a single file named PHPExcel.php in the classes folder but i don't understand you concern ... can you please tell me where i do these changes in the PHPExcel library.

Comment: PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP);

Comment: Can you please tell me the proper location where i can change zip method

Comment: I have used the code ..
At the beginning of my PHP file I have:

require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP);

And getting an error
Warning: stream_wrapper_unregister() [function.stream-wrapper-unregister]: Unable to unregister protocol zip:// in /home/crazyfirew/domains/thundershow.nl/public_html/kruidenier/admin/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/ZipStreamWrapper.php on line 69